# Defining a spring bean with an alias and null value

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean definition like below.

```
<bean id="resolver" class="com.Foo">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="transportFactory"/>
</bean>
```

This definition is imported in other spring files. One of those files can define transportFactory normally,

```
<bean id="transportFactory" class="com.Bar"/>
```

However, the other needs to define transportFactory as "null". Is this possible in spring?

```
<bean id="transportFactory" value="null"/>
```

obviously doesn't work but any pointers to the correct syntax would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Two beans with same name cannot be created `transportFactory`.

IMO You can have two different definition for resolver.

```
<bean id="resolver1" class="com.Foo">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="transportFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="resolver2" class="com.Foo">
    <constructor-arg index="0" /><null /></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use @Bean annotation on transportFactory method which returns a null.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this workaround use factory which will return null .

```
<bean id="springServiceCarInstance" factory-bean="springServiceStaticFactory" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

Here, return null from createInstance method of factory class.